# change a column values with calculations

Tags: python, pandas

here is my dataframe : [dataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuOGR.png)

i just want to multiply all values in "sous_nutrition" by 10^6

When i do this code `proportion_sous_nutrition_2017['sous_nutrition'] = proportion_sous_nutrition_2017.sous_nutrition * 1000000`

It gave me this ... [newDataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8rKg.png)

I want to multiply by 1 million because the value is precised 'in million' and it will make easier to calculate other things after...

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: What's the dtype of `sous_nutrition`. If string/object change it.

Comment: try this: proportion_sous_nutrition_2017['sous_nutrition'] = proportion_sous_nutrition_2017.sous_nutrition.astype(int) * 1000000

Comment: float rather than int

Comment: The question is why your column `'sous_nutrition'` has the type `str` instead of `float`?

Comment: @Corralien i have no idea why it is str i'm a noob and i just load a .csv and started working on it 3 days ago !

Comment: This is the meaning of my question. If `pd.read_csv` cannot convert the column` `'sous_nutrition'` to` float` it's because there is another problem. Use `astype (float)` will (probably) not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_numeric(..., errors='coerce')` to force to `NaN` values that cannot be converted into numeric.

Try:

```py
proportion_sous_nutrition_2017['sous_nutrition'] = 1e6 * pd.to_numeric(proportion_sous_nutrition_2017['sous_nutrition'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: If you do that, the OP can't do the difference between real original NaN values and NaN from the cast.

Comment: I just saw the additional information that the bad values are in the form of `'< 0.1'`. In the same spirit, converting `'< 0.1'` into `0.1` seems wrong to me. We could convert `'< 0.'` into e.g. `'0.0'`, so that `'< 0.1'` would become `0.01`, etc. But I don't like that kind of magic handling. Perhaps better to simply replace by 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
# create a new column called 'sous_nutrition_float' that only has 1.1 or 0.3 etc. and removes the > or < etc.
proportion_sous_nutrition_2017['sous_nutrition_float'] = proportion_sous_nutrition_2017['sous_nutrition'].str.extract(r'([0-9.]+)').astype(float)

proportion_sous_nutrition_2017['sous_nutrition'] = proportion_sous_nutrition_2017.sous_nutrition_float * 1000000
```

To find the dtypes run:

```
print(proportion_sous_nutrition_2017.info())
```

The types should be float or int before multiplying etc.

```
 #   Column                Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                --------------  -----  
 0   sous_nutrition        3 non-null      float64
 1   sous_nutrition_float  3 non-null      float64
......
....
..
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be convert all `< xxx` to `xxx`

```
>>> df['sous_nutrition']
0      1.2
1      NaN
2    < 0.1
Name: sous_nutrition, dtype: object

>>> df['sous_nutrition'].str.replace('<', '').astype(float)
0    1.2
1    NaN
2    0.1
Name: sous_nutrition, dtype: float64
```

So, this should work:

```
proportion_sous_nutrition_2017['sous_nutrition_float'] = proportion_sous_nutrition_2017['sous_nutrition'].str.replace('<', '').astype(float) * 1000000
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you have is due to the fact that the format of your column 'sous_nutrition' is not float as you expect, but string (or object). For the solution, you need to change the format as indicated

Hamza usman ghani

If there are errors when changing the type, try this code:

```py
df['sous_nutrition'] = pd.to_numeric(df['sous_nutrition'], downcast='float', errors='coerce')

and then you do this corectly:
df['sous_nutrition'] = df['sous_nutrition']*1000000
```